# PySide6 runs code without issues but nothing appears

Tags: python-3.x, pyside6, qmainwindow, qapplication

So, I build a code that will start my app, and when I run it, nothing appears on the screen the same as PyCharm doesn't solve any issues.

```
import sys
import rec_rc
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from ui_Main_Window import Ui_MainWindow

class ExpenceTracker(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ExpenceTracker, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__ExpenceTracker__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExpenceTracker()
    window.show()
```

If you need more information. Just write in comments.

I tried many variables of code, but in some I have issues and another gives the same result.

```
class ExpenceTracker(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow).__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self)



if __name__ == '__ExpenceTracker__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExpenceTracker()
    window.show()
```

It just the example of what I'm building.

Comment: TYPO(s): change to `if __name__ == '__main__':` and there append `sys.exit(app.exec())` after the existing lines, but within the same indentation block. Also, you can safely use `super()` without any arguments, but if you *do* use them, use the correct ones (the usage in the second snippet is wrong).

Comment: Hi, i do as you said and getting another errors.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 22, in <module>
    window = ExpenceTracker()
            
   line 10, in __init__
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
  line 124, in setupUi
    self.outcome_lable.setStyleSheet(u"color: white;\n",
   
AttributeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout' object has no attribute 'setStyleSheet'

Comment: I checked my Ui code and it's looks good, also i run it beside of app starter code, and i don't get any errors in line 124,

Comment: Based on the code you provided, that could not happen, so you are probably doing something else we know nothing about (and therefore we need a more comprehensive [mre]), or you attempted to modify the file generated by pyuic, which is considered bad practice and highly discouraged (as the warning on top of such files clearly suggests).

Comment: Ok, i tested start app code on my other app window, and it runs good.
So there some problem in window code, pycharm give errors on line 132 
self.outcome_lable.setStyleSheet(u"color: white;\n"
"\n"
"background: none;\n"
"border: none;\n"
"font-size: 16pt;\n"
"paddiing-top: 10px;")
I build this Ui in qtdesigner and transformed it from .qrc to .py throw pyside6-uci command
Also when i have file named rec_rc where icon is based, when i transformed my main window i get it wrong writen "rec-rc_rc'', but in second window it was ok, and second is working fine
It's corrupted file or code?

Comment: The error is 
AttributeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout' object has no attribute 'setStyleSheet'
does QHBoxLayout can't have StyleSheets?

Comment: Layout managers are not widgets, so no, they obviously cannot be styled. Also, the uic utility works with `.ui` files, not `.qrc` ones. As already said, please provide a [mre], we cannot make assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for advise, i fix it, it was problem with QHBoxLayout i change it to QLable and now it works perfect, i changed all boxes to lables but probably i forgot about it. how can i close this question?